# Как сделать такой блок c обтекающими картинками?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Долго ломал голову и так и не смог на чисто css, тут без какой либо библиотеки Js или Jquery не обойтись или есть решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть ссылка потыкать? Как ведет себя это произведение искусства при изменении ширины окна? Может это вообще одна большая картинка с, расставленными заранее, элементами исходя из их размеров...

Comment: @Leonid это фото из фигмы, дали тех задание на собеседование, все реализовал кроме этого(

Comment: Так как именно звучало задание?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом css можно сделать [так](https://codepen.io/pilaton/pen/BaWqeYZ).

```
{~}
```

Comment: Мне кажется там картинки разных высот и данный вариант не катит.